# What the duck is this?

Tags: discussion

I don't know whether this belongs in main or meta, so I'll start here.

I seem to have developed a sudden case of 'Duck', bottom right of every SE page [except meta] - it reminds me of the old Microsoft paperclip/puppy that I always loathed.

[image]

It seems to only be on Stack Exchange pages, so I'm assuming it's some new 'feature'. I'm not going to click on it to find out what it is.

Anybody know how to get rid of it?

Comment: I presume an early April Fools?

Comment: If it is, it's very early. It's still saturday morning here; I've got one more sleep before I thought I needed to be on the lookout for those.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE [**Stack Exchange has been taken over by a rubber duck!**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308564/222623)

Comment: Do I win a prize for being first?  

Comment: A gold star to you for combatting quackery quickly and foiling a possibly fowl situation.

Comment: Ah! the famed rubber duck debugging technique. I find [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308578/387221) answer on SE meta quite descriptive.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, you can indeed get an upvote. 

Comment: It's not early; in the Eastern-most parts of the world, it's already April 1st.

Comment: I posted this at approx 11:00 BST [10:00 UTC] Saturday March 31st... at which time it was [just] Sunday on Christmas Island. So, yes, it did appear at midnight April1st for the very few people living in that time zone. However, the immediate association with April 1st simply wasn't going to happen for me before noon, the day before, whilst tucking into a bacon sandwich...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## April Fools? Rubber Duck Problem Solving

I suspect an April Fools that has launched too soon. See [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) and [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging):

> In software engineering, rubber duck debugging or rubber ducking is a method of debugging code. The name is a reference to a story in the book The Pragmatic Programmer in which a programmer would carry around a rubber duck and debug their code by forcing themselves to explain it, line-by-line, to the duck.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg7Ba.png) Many other terms exist for this technique, often involving different inanimate objects.

Clicking **Ask the duck!** starts recording with the microphone – oddly no security confirmation from Safari for this permission.

After a moment of spinning a graphic, a visual and audible **Quack** occurs, followed by the following message:

[image]

Comment: Visual [*and audible*](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/quack.mp3) quack! There's no confirmation because there's no actual microphone access, try pressing No when asked if you have a microphone. See Meta.SE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck

Comment: So that's why it "activates" the microphone even when you say you don't have one. I thought it was somehow bugged.